# Intel 6280 WiFi Linux driver

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, linux-mint

I've recently bought a new notebook, which has an `Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 (802.11 ac/a/b/g/n, 2x2 Dual Band, Wi-Fi + Bluetooth combo)` installed. Neither Linux Mint nor Ubuntu (which is closely the same) are able to use it. It is detected indeed, and `lshw` lists it as follows:

```
*-pci:1
  description: PCI bridge
  product: Intel Corporation
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 1c.2
  bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
  version: f1
  width: 32 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
  configuration: driver=pcieport
  resources: irq:18 memory:f4000000-f40fffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: Wireless 8260
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
    version: 3a
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:f4000000-f4001fff
```

How can I get the WiFi to work under Linux Mint (or similiar)? There must be a way!

Thanks in advance,
Lukas

**Edit 1**: As requested, here's the output of `lspci -vnn | grep Network`:

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
```

Since I'm afraid that this will not be sufficient, I've uploaded the whole output of `lspci -vnn` [here](https://gist.github.com/LukeLR/7aaad7acc64939c864e3). I hope that someone's able to help! ;)

Comment: The ouput of `lspci -vnn | grep Network` ?

Comment: @GAD3R I've added the output to my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Driver modules for the mentioned Intel 6280 WiFi Chipset are included in the latest linux kernel version 4.5. You can manually upgrade your linux kernel to the latest version in order to use these modules as follows:

1. Check the currently installed kernel version on your system by opening a terminal and typing `uname -a`. You'll get something like this:
   `Linux <computer name> 3.14.64-036757-generic #201603140130 SMP Mon Mar 14 05:32:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
   In this case, kernel version 3.14.64 is installed. If your installed kernel is already 4.5, you don't need to upgrade your kernel.
2. Type `file /sbin/init` in your terminal to find out if your installation is 32 or 64bits. Your output might start like this:
   `/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, ...`
   In this case, it's a 64bit-installation.
3. Go to the kernel download repository for your distribution. In this case it's the download page for the ubuntu kernel packages: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/, other distributions have similiar download pages. (*You can also get the kernel sources on http://kernel.org and compile yourself, this is not covered here.*)
4. Scroll down to the latest available build (in this case 4.5) and click to enter the directory. Download the following files for **32bit**:

   1. [linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_i386.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_i386.deb)
   2. [linux-headers-4.5.0-040500_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_all.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_all.deb)
   3. [linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_i386.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_i386.deb)

   Or for **64bit**:

   1. [linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb)
   2. [linux-headers-4.5.0-040500_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_all.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_all.deb)
   3. [linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb)

   Of course, if you're trying to install a different version from 4.5, the file names will include that version number instead of `4.5.0-xxxxxx`.
5. Open a Terminal and type `cd <folder path>`, replace `<folder path>` with the path of the folder you downloaded the three kernel files to
6. Make sure that folder doesn't contain any other `.deb`-files than the three you just downloaded, otherwise move them to another folder and `cd` to it
7. Run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` while still in the folder with the downloaded files.
8. Wait for the process to complete, then run `sudo update-grub` in case the installation didn't do that on it's own
9. Reboot your system, then open a Terminal and type `uname -a` again to verify that the new kernel version is properly installed. It should now look like this:
   `Linux Lukas-TP-Mint 4.5.0-040500-generic #201603140130 SMP Mon Mar 14 05:32:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Your WiFi should work properly now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `iwlwifi`

first install `linux-headers` and `build-essential`

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

then download backports from here [backports](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/09/23/backports-20150923.tar.gz)
Extract and navigate to the directory backports-3.16-1 and type the following command:

```
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Load the module

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that! I see that the backport is from September 2015, isn't that a bit old?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the issue. Still no wifi detected, only wired connection is available, both in system tray network menu and in `ifconfig`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll give it a try ;)

Comment: Doesn't work, it just says `Cannot find device "wlan0"`. Any ideas?

Comment: `wireless-tools is already the newest version`. But `modprobe -r iwlwifi` fails with `rmmod: ERROR: missing module name. modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi`. Any ideas? Adding `-a` doesn't fix it, `modprobe iwlwifi` seems to exit fine.

Comment: This command works, but still `cannot find device wlan0`. Any ideas?